# Magento in maintenance mode after importing database from live to test

Tags: magento-1.9, database, import, importexport, magerun

I created a dump of my live database and imported it into staging by using n98-magerun.

```
./n98-magerun.phar db:import live.sql
```

But now my website is in maintenance mode, even though there is no maintenance.flag file.

I also tried to deactivate maintenance mode by using n98-magerun:

```
n98-magerun sys:maintenance
```

Response: Maintenance mode off

But it still fails and the maintenance site shows.

Comment: Where it shows maintenance in live or staging? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Did you get any issue in your log files ?

Comment: @SukumarGorai, it shows the maintenance page on staging now.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: The error message `Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'magerecaptcha' already exists` appears. I guess I also have to update the filesystem.

Comment: @Black Magento is trying to re-create that table even though it already exists. You can try deleting the table and running `n98-magerun.phar sys:setup:run` to run the setup scripts manually to see if there are anymore errors.

Comment: That worked! :) Now I can see my site again! Please write your comment as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've imported a SQL file into a Magento database it's best to run `n98-magerun.phar sys:setup:run` to try manually running the setup scripts (Instead of letting the frontend manage this) so you can easily view any errors that occur during setup.

In this case, Magento is trying to re-create table `magerecaptcha` even though it already exists. You can try deleting the table and running n98-magerun.phar sys:setup:run again to see if there are any further errors.